# How do I deal with this Forcats install error

Tags: r, forcats

I downloaded r and now its refusing to import datasets because the package forcats is not installed. When I try to install it gives me this error:

> install.packages("forcats") WARNING: Rtools is required to build R
> packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install
> the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:
>
> https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/ Installing package into
> ‘C:/Users/chimerab/OneDrive - IARC/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’ (as
> ‘lib’ is unspecified) also installing the dependencies ‘cli’,
> ‘lifecycle’, ‘rlang’
>
> There are binary versions available but the source versions are
> later:
> binary source needs_compilation cli        2.5.0  3.6.1              TRUE lifecycle  1.0.0  1.0.3             FALSE rlang     0.4.11  1.1.1
> TRUE forcats    0.5.1  1.0.0             FALSE
>
> Binaries will be installed trying URL
> 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/cli_2.5.0.zip'
> Content type 'application/zip' length 534931 bytes (522 KB) downloaded
> 522 KB
>
> trying URL
> 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/rlang_0.4.11.zip'
> Content type 'application/zip' length 1224139 bytes (1.2 MB)
> downloaded 1.2 MB
>
> package ‘cli’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked package
> ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>
> The downloaded binary packages are in
> C:\Users\chimerab\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpQ1lIAK\downloaded_packages
> installing the source packages ‘lifecycle’, ‘forcats’
>
> trying URL
> 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/lifecycle_1.0.3.tar.gz' Content
> type 'application/x-gzip' length 106854 bytes (104 KB) downloaded 104
> KB
>
> trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/forcats_1.0.0.tar.gz'
> Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 294183 bytes (287 KB)
> downloaded 287 KB
>
> - installing *source* package 'lifecycle' ...
>   ** package 'lifecycle' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>   ** using staged installation
>   ** R
>   ** inst
>   ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
>   namespace 'rlang' 0.4.11 is being loaded, but >= 1.0.6 is required
>   Calls:  ... withCallingHandlers -> loadNamespace ->
>   namespaceImport -> loadNamespace Execution halted ERROR: lazy loading
>   failed for package 'lifecycle'
> - removing 'C:/Users/chimerab/OneDrive - IARC/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/lifecycle' Warning in
>   install.packages :   installation of package ‘lifecycle’ had non-zero
>   exit status ERROR: dependency 'lifecycle' is not available for package
>   'forcats'
> - removing 'C:/Users/chimerab/OneDrive - IARC/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/forcats' Warning in install.packages
>   :   installation of package ‘forcats’ had non-zero exit status
>
> The downloaded source packages are in
> ‘C:\Users\chimerab\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpQ1lIAK\downloaded_package

Comment: It seems that your R installation is quite old 3.6 compare to the latest 4.3.1. Update your R first then I think your install command will run smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```r
install.packages("rlang")
install.packages("forcats")
```

It sounds like `forcats` is installing dependencies `rlang` and `lifecycle`, but `lifecycle`'s installation is failing because it requires a more up to date version of `rlang`. By explicitly installing `rlang`, you should be able to install `forcats` successfully.